Transpose "Year" by "Month" DataFrame to a DataFrame with "Date" and "Value" columns
The Problem
I have a Pandas DataFrame with the current layout of data:

I simply want to convert it to a Pandas DataFrame that looks like:
         Date       Value
0     01-Jan-1914    2.0
1     01-Feb-1914    1.0
2     01-Mar-1914    1.0
...      ...         ...
108   01-Jan-2024    3.1
109   01-Feb-2024    3.2
110   01-Mar-2024    3.5

A new DataFrame with a single column for the date and another for the corresponding value.
Attempts So Far
I found the pd.DataFrame.stack() method that, once I drop the Year column with DataFrame.drop(columns=["Year"]), got me most of the way there.

Though this gives me a pd.Series object with a multi-index that I'm struggling to work with to get the final date output.
The temptation is to iterate through the rows but this would be rather slow and I imagine there already exists a Pandas or NumPy method that can achieve the desired output I need.
Thanks in advance for any help!

If you have this dataframe:
   Year  Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
0  1914    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
1  1915   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81   91  101  111  121

Then you can do:
out = (
    df.set_index("Year")
    .stack()
    .rename_axis(index=["Year", "Month"])
    .reset_index(name="Value")
)

out["Date"] = "01-" + out.pop("Month").astype(str) + "-" + out.pop("Year").astype(str)

print(out[["Date", "Value"]])

Prints:
           Date  Value
0   01-Jan-1914      1
1   01-Feb-1914      2
2   01-Mar-1914      3
3   01-Apr-1914      4
4   01-May-1914      5
5   01-Jun-1914      6
6   01-Jul-1914      7
7   01-Aug-1914      8
8   01-Sep-1914      9
9   01-Oct-1914     10
10  01-Nov-1914     11
11  01-Dec-1914     12
12  01-Jan-1915     11
13  01-Feb-1915     21
14  01-Mar-1915     31
15  01-Apr-1915     41
16  01-May-1915     51
17  01-Jun-1915     61
18  01-Jul-1915     71
19  01-Aug-1915     81
20  01-Sep-1915     91
21  01-Oct-1915    101
22  01-Nov-1915    111
23  01-Dec-1915    121


Thanks for the help. Much appreciated!
I also added df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]) to get a datetime object - something I forgot to add to the main question.
